Dynamic roulette in html css js (WITHOUT CANVAS)
I need a way to create a roulette in css html js but without using canvas and that is dynamic.
I can't find anything about how to do this but DYNAMIC.
NO CANVAS
So far I have only been able to do this, but they are not even the same size and it is not adaptable at all, because if you put 10 elements they overlap.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Div</title>

</head>
<body>

    <div class="roulette">
        <div class="element" style="--i: 0; background: #00aeff;"></div>
        <div class="element" style="--i: 1; background: #2f00ff;"></div>
        <div class="element" style="--i: 2; background: #00ff95;"></div>
        <div class="element" style="--i: 3; background: #eeff00; "></div>
        <div class="element" style="--i: 4; background: #ff00dd;"></div>
        <div class="element" style="--i: 5; background: red;"></div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>

<style>
*{
    --size: 80px;
    --n: 6;
    --degs:calc(360 / var(--n));
}


.roulette{
    width: calc(var(--size) * 2);
    height: calc(var(--size) * 2);
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: black;
} 

.element{
    width: var(--size);
    height: var(--size);
    position: absolute;
    transform-origin: bottom right;
    transform: rotate(calc(var(--i) * var(--degs) * 1deg));
}


It's possible but do aim for something within scope, this isn't easily done as a beginner project.  Skipping out on canvas has many draw-backs as well, major one is access to low level drawing API and its hardware acceleration.
